# remove node in /node?page=1

Tags: redirection, paging, uri, nodes

I am using [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) which automatically convert /node?page=1 to /?page=1 when click on pagination. everything working fine but i want also remove /node and just want /?page=1 when mouse hover on pagination. you can also refer [my site](http://topbargains.com.au:8080/?page=3) and check its pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hook_menu_alter` 
below code not completely correct but can get you good idea about how can you do it

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
 $temp= $items['node/%'] ;
$items['page?%']=$temp;
}
```